# Rendering React components mapped from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've spent several days trying to figure this out so hopefully y'all can  help me. I want to get posts from a Cloud Firestore database and display them on a React app.

My data in Firestore is structured like this:

> [project]/NewsPosts/[documents]

Each document is structured in firestore like this:

> [randomly generated id]
>
> - title: [string]
> - body: [string]

I have been getting the posts by doing the following:

```
let posts= [];

//db = firebase.firestore();

db.collections.("NewsPosts").get().then((snapshot) => (
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => (
    posts.push({
      id: doc.id,
      title: doc.data().title,
      body: doc.data().body
    })
  ))
));
```

This successfully creates an array of objects with the information I want, so fetching the data isn't the issue. However, when I go to map this array to create posts, nothings is being created. I've tried every variation of mapping arrays to create components, but it doesn't work.

However, when I hardcode an array of objects and map that one, it works. For example, this works with the hardcoded array of objects:

```
//hard is the hardcoded array
let displayPosts = hard.map((p) => (
    <div key={p.id}>
        <h1>{p.title}</h1>
        <p>{p.body}</p>
    </div>
))

return(
    <Page>
        {displayPosts}
    </Page>
);
```

When I compared the hardcoded array and the other array in the browser console, the arrays look different.

I imagine it's this difference in the arrays that is causing the problem.

This is how they look in the browser console, if there's 2 elements:

```
(2)[{...},{...}]      (hardcoded)
[]                    (array filled from firestore)
```

**However, everything else about the arrays are the same in the browser console.**

Why do these arrays look different? Is this what's keeping me from mapping the objects at each index correctly? How do I get the mapping to work on an array of objects fetched from Firestore?

Thank you in advance for your help! This has caused me quite the headache.

Comment: can you please show the cod where to try to map over the array?

Comment: Of course! I edited my original post to add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this!

I wasn't changing it immutably.

This makes it work correctly:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        posts: []
    }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    db.collection("NewsPosts").get().then((snapshot) => (
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => (
            this.setState((prevState) => ({
                posts: [...prevState.posts, {
                    postID: doc.id,
                    title: doc.data().title,
                    body: doc.data().body,
                    featured: doc.data().featured
                }]
            }))
        ))
    ))
}
```

Comment: I've run in to this problem many times and keep coming back to this answer. Always fixes it!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to your question is still missing a right key. So the full answer to Mango's question (and own answer) will be:

```
class Sample extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    posts: []
  }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    db.collection("NewsPosts").get().then((snapshot) => (
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => (
            this.setState((prevState) => ({
                posts: [...prevState.posts, {
                    postID: doc.id,
                    title: doc.data().title,
                    body: doc.data().body,
                    featured: doc.data().featured
                }]
            }))
        ))
    ))
}

    render() {
        let displayPosts = this.state.posts.map((p) => (
            <div key={p.postID}>
                <h1>{p.title}</h1>
                <p>{p.body}</p>
            </div>
        ))

        return(
            <Page>
                {displayPosts}
            </Page>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understadning of your question, I think the following code should help you solve your issue.

```
class Sample extends React.Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let posts = [];
        db.collections.("NewsPosts").get().then((snapshot) => (
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => (
                posts.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    title: doc.data().title,
                    body: doc.data().body
                })
            ))
            this.setState({ posts })
        ));
    }

    render() {
        let displayPosts = this.state.posts.map((p) => (
            <div key={p.id}>
                <h1>{p.title}</h1>
                <p>{p.body}</p>
            </div>
        ))

        return(
            <Page>
                {displayPosts}
            </Page>
        );
    }

}
```

The main point this code is highlighting, is that react is data driven. Essentially, you have an array on state called posts, which you will map over to render your data. When this array is empty, as in the case before the data is fetched like on initial render, no items will get rendered. Once the data comes back from the db, the data gets added to your posts array on state. The `setState` method is called to force a new render, but this time we have data to display.

If this answer indicates I misunderstood your question, please do follow up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Nothing is being displayed. I'm not sure if the posts are being added to the arrays with this but I will have to test it later.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late, but if anyone is still searching for an answer to this, use `querySnapshot.docs.map( (doc) => <some element>)`. This way you do not need to use useState if you do not want to, such as in Server Components if you are using NextJs 13